# GridSearch LightGBM with GPU

Tags: python, gpu, grid-search, lightgbm

How do you use a GPU to do GridSearch with LightGBM? If you just want to train a lgb model with default parameters, you can do:

```
dataset = lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train)
lgb.train({'device': 'gpu'}, dataset)
```

To do GridSearch, it would be great to do something like this:

```
lgbm_classifier = lgb.LGBMClassifier()

param_grid = {
    'learning_rate': [...],
    'n_estimators': [...],
}

GridSearchCV(lgbm_classifier, param_grid)
```

But it doesn't look like `lgb.LGBMClassifier()` has a parameter for `device` like `lgb.train()` does. How do you set it to use the GPU?

Comment: Have you tried using `lgb.LGBMClassifier('device': 'gpu')`? The [scikit API docs](http://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#scikit-learn-api) suggest that you can pass extra keyword arguments (same as params dict in `train()`), but I cannot test that because I dont have a GPU.

Comment: I think you mean `lgb.LGBMClassifier(device='gpu')`, which does not give any errors but does not seem to activate the GPU

Comment: Yes. Indeed I meant that. And also I just read the Note below that page, that `"**kwargs is not supported in sklearn, it may cause unexpected issues."` Upon further inspection, it looks like it has been handled correctly and should work. How are you detecting that its not activating?

Comment: Are you getting any difference when you use the GridSearchCV and when you dont? Have the library been compiled to use a GPU?

Comment: I don't think it's activating because nothing is printed to console signaling that it's being used. When I run something like `lgb.train({'device': 'gpu'}, data)`, it prints status messages from the GPU, and when I run `lgb.train({'device': 'cpu'}, data)`, nothing is printed out. This is why I suspected that it is not hitting the gpu

Comment: I can confirm that the `'device'` param is successfully passed on to the `train()` method which is [called under the hood here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/python-package/lightgbm/sklearn.py#L468). So make sure that you are on the latest version of lgbm and scikit.

Comment: Yeah actually upon further inspection, the GPU isn't printing anything but when run on a large dataset there is a noticeable difference in time, so I think it's working after all. Feel free to make an answer to the Q and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

LGBMClassifier() does have the `device`/`device_type` parameter which can be set to 'gpu' as per the [parameter docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#device_type).

To set it to 'gpu', you can configure GPU-based LGBM. A couple of community members have demonstrated how to do that [here](https://medium.com/@vipulgote4/how-to-build-and-install-lightgbm-for-gpu-acceleration-2b53f0066c02) and [here](https://www.thekerneltrip.com/machine-learning/lgbmgpu/). The second resource also has something called `glances` (on PyPi.org) to observe the GPU usage which addresses the comments raised.